# Making a case-sensitive custom Google search

Tags: api, case-sensitive, google-custom-search

The most promising option for performing a case-sensitive search on the internet seems to be through the Google Custom Search API. But after reading through some of the docs, I'm still not able to tell if it's possible to filter by case/capitalization.

Could someone tell me how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, Google Custom Search doesn't support case-sensitive search.

The best you could do is grab the results using the API then use some other code to filter the snippets.